# How to check valid email address using smtp mail from SQL Server - stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, smtp, email-validation

I am sending mail using SMTP in SQL server stored procedure. Now I need to check whether the email address is valid/active/exist or not. Email address format is okay. For example, abc@gmail.com is a email address where mail will be sent. The format is okay but before sending mail I need to check that the address is active/exist. If address is valid/, then the mail will be delivered.

Can any one help me?

Comment: There isn't really any universal way to check if email address exists or not

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I think you could do would be go to the domain address of whoever assigned the the email and click lost password and see if it says the the email exists or does not exist. I would also look into the API of the email provider because if they give that information out publicly when you request a lost password then it may or may not be available through an API of some sort.